# Typescript does not identify error when using generics

Tags: typescript, generics

When I use the following code, typescript does not complain that I try to pass `IAction<Product>` instead of the expected `IAction<Customer>`:

```
interface IAction<T> {
    canExecute<T>(input: T): void;
}

interface Product {
    name: string,
}

interface Customer {
    displayName?: string;
    description?: string;
}

class MyAction implements IAction<Product> {
    public canExecute<Product>(product: Product): void {
    }
}

class MyMenuItemAction {
        constructor(private action: IAction<Customer>) {
    }
}

function foo(action: IAction<Customer>): void {
}

const action: IAction<Product> = new MyAction();
const menuItem = new MyMenuItemAction(action);
foo(action);
```

But if I remove the `<T>` from the canExecute function in the IAction interface, it does complain about it:

```
interface IAction<T> {
    canExecute(input: T): void;
}
```

Is this a bug in typescript?

Comment: This is not a bug in Typescript. With that extra <T> you are actually declaring a new type parameter for the method, different than the one the interface declares.

Comment: But I'm still confused why I can pass IAction<Product> to a function which expects IAction<Customer>...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your interface to avoid override of a generic

```js
interface IAction<T> {
    canExecute(input: T): void; // <- remove <T> from here.
    // canExecute<T> means there's another generic that has a conflict
    // with IAction<T>
}
```

Then update MyAction

```js
class MyAction implements IAction<Product> {
    public canExecute(product: Product): void { // <- remove <Product>
    }
}
```

Profit: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEFmAexAHgBUA+ZAbwChlrkE4QBRADwgQFdIAKUABw4C5khAJSCAbjmAATANwUAvhQqhIsRCgAKUHFLZZyVGiDgBbCIIDOYKKADmAGgVKV0eEmQBhNlZxmoBmmQpYAseABs4AE8AOVMIAH5Lazs5QKkICwQbHmw8ROQrGxBbOUUKBAiLC2QAWUjMXJBkYBNwiDNwaowsXAItHT0wUkpAvgAjMOAEWnpmVg4ITh5tXSxBftWwUWQJaQCaRTKKuCrayJqIEDZUSBMG3v3A6gQ8QsGcKCWbMThIZERGoJuo18F4fH5iMJHshDkoYGwQD08MgYDgcJwAb0gfc8KDvGBfNBIeJJFIDEdXmB-kiQNiafgNoNSABeZAgCAAdzOOJAnGEcheICsyA611uyFZ7K5dQuVxu7R5GJp-IoqPRmLw-KAA)

Comment: Thanks! can you please clarify what you mean by: "canExecute<T> means there's another generic that has a conflict with IAction<T>"

Comment: once you have `<T>` in definition - it means there's a generic. In your case you say `IAction<T>` has a generic `T`, then you say `canExecute<T>` has a generic `T`, but this `T` is an other `T` (name collision), and when you say `IAction<Product>` it doesn't set type to `canExecute<T>`. Therefore it's fine to have `IAction<Product>.canExecute<Customer>` and that's why you don't get an error.

Comment: If it answers your question - might you mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: this: `IAction<Product>.canExecute<Customer>` I understand. But I'm still confused why I can pass `IAction<Product>` to a function which expects `IAction<Customer>`...?

Comment: because `IAction<Product>` doesn't narrow the 2nd `canExecute<T>` and it can be any type. It means it accepts a top level `Product` only and `canExecute` accepts anything as its `T` and anything fits `Customer` therefore you don't get an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything fits Customer"?

Comment: I mean `canExecute<T>` can be `canExecute<Customer>` or `canExecute<Product>` or `canExecute<Any>`, because `IAction<Product>` doesn't narrow it.

Comment: When you add `<Product>` or `<Customer>` to the method declaration (like in `public canExecute<Product>(product: Product): void`) you are not actually narrowing the restriction of the parameter type `<T>` that you declared in the interface. You are declaring a new type parameter named `<Product>` (which is not the same as your interface `Product`, but a distinct type), and then declaring that the parameter `product` is the same type as this type parameter. You could have any identifier there, cause it is just a name for a *new* type parameter.